# Twilio act as connector

Tags: twilio

I was wondering if Twilio can act as "connector".

I use a Cloud based CRM with possibility to connect telephony system via WebRTC. I already own a IP telephony infrastructure but WebRTC is not supported.

Is possible to use Twilio as the scenario below:

Cloud CRM (WebRTC client embedded) --> WebRTC --> Twilio --> SIP Trunk --> My own VoIP server?

Comment: Are you using Twilio Webrtc client or what infrastructure? If using Twilio, use Twilio Webrtc client and use Dial sip verb to call sip URIs.

Comment: I don't use Twilio at the moment, but I think of.

Answer (score 0):

As spicyramen suggests, using [Twilio WebRTC Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/client) and [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) you can use the `<Dial>` `<Sip>` verbs to call SIP URIs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Dial>
    <Sip>
        sip:jack@example.com
    </Sip>
</Dial>
</Response>
```